# How to change window.status by onmouseover of a createElement()

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, createelement

I wish to change window status by overing a link created by createElement(), but it doesn't seems to work (I'm trying with Chrome).

**It seems to be possible like Google mades it with the redirected links in his index.** By mouse overing links in his index, you should see an href in the window status that is not the real link clicked (google redirection). So, please, don't tell me that browsers block this for security reasons, and help me to do it :-)

I've tried the [**following**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxxDu/)

```
function createLink(id) 
{
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.onmouseover = function(){window.status='test';};
  link.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  link.id = '1';
  link.rel = 'nofollow';
  link.style.cssText ='border-bottom:2px solid;';  
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.innerHTML = 'Link';
  id.appendChild(link);
}

myElement=document.getElementById('id_text');
createLink(myElement);
```

But the window status only displays the href value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does a very neat trick: they change the link when the main mouse button gets pressed (`onmousedown`). You can check this very easily: hover above a link and then press the main mouse button. The link changes.

In order to achieve such a result you would have to use

```
function createLink(id) 
{
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  ///  vvvvvvvvvvv
  link.onmousedown = function(){this.href = 'http://www.example.com';};
  ///  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  link.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  link.id = '1';
  link.rel = 'nofollow';
  link.style.cssText ='border-bottom:2px solid;';  
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.innerHTML = 'Link';
  id.appendChild(link);
}

myElement=document.getElementById('id_text');
createLink(myElement);
```

Note that redirection to other pages than the user expected is rude and may sometimes be identified as malicious behavior.

Comment: It's only to simplify url displayed... not to fool users

Answer (score 3):

Modern day browsers block changing the status. It has to be enabled by the user in the browser's settings.

Chrome has the flag in about:config look for `dom.disable_window_status_change`

It is disabled since it is a security concern.

Now since you say I am wrong with google, look at the links!

```
<a href="http://staplesadvantage.com/" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','14','AFQjCNER8Nv_Zhb-txDtR-b9O09SVzuTpQ','Ab3MA_Y5pbwgWlo68Wp1kA','0CI8BEBYwDQ','','',event)">Business Solutions | <em>Staples</em> Advantage</a>
```

`rwt`, catches the link, cancels the click, and does the redirection!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't reply my question, look at http://www.google.com and look at your window status ^^

Comment: By mouse overing links in his index, you should see an href in the window status that is not the real link clicked (google redirection)

Comment: @Valky, look at what Google does! Look at the source! The href is the real link. They capture the link with an onmousedown and send the redirection URL. So yes, they do not change the window.status!  `<a href="http://staplesadvantage.com/" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,...,event)">Business Solutions | <em>Staples</em> Advantage</a>` Going to reverse the downvote?

Comment: This is a beginning to reply to my question.

Comment: But, finally it displays a window status that is not the real link clicked. So it changes it in a way... keep cool and carry on :-)

Comment: Google Search... **Zzz. What's the point** then, to disable it in the browser "due to security concerns", yet allow a workaround as long as JavaScript is enabled..... That fully defeats the purpose. Any malicious party can simply do `<a href="http://safesite.com">` to spoof the status bar, then use JS to redirect the user to `http://malicious.com`.... Yes, if the user disabled JS it wouldn't work, but in the first place if the user had JS disabled, changing `window.status`  wouldn't work too and there would have been no security issues regarding the feature!