# iframe top window status change

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a link in Iframe and am redirecting users to final destination say `x.com` through an intermediate php script. However I want the users to see the final destination link in their status bar when they mouseover the link.

I have tried everything to change the `window.status`(in desperation) but nothing works. I have tried so far :

```
    <a onmouseover='window.top.status="x.com";return true;'....
    <a onmouseover='window.parent.status="x.com";return true;'....
    <a onmouseover='parent.window.status="x.com";return true;'....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been disabled in most modern (and even not so modern) browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.status

If you want to do this, you can create a function onload to create the link element, and change it on mousedown. There is a good example here: [How to change window.status by onmouseover of a createElement()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750767/how-to-change-window-status-by-onmouseover-of-a-createelement)

Alternatively, you can skip the status all together and use a tooltip or something else to let users know where they will be forwarded.

Comment: Thanks @spacebean, never thought it was not allowed. I finally used
`<a target='_blank' onclick='this.href ="redirect.php";' href='x.com'>Link</a>`

I tried on IE8, FF and Chrome and it worked. Actually this is better approach as if JS is disabled the link will still be followed.

Answer (score 0):

It's better you to have the desired href inside  tag. So users will see the needed string in status bar. Then change href on click to go to the needed php script.